# parse program with tokens at fixed positions in a line

Tags: antlr4

I am new to Antlr and need to write a parser for a legacy assembly code that *may* have line numbers in fixed columns. Also, certain columns have significance - whether its a comment, continuation, etc. How can I detect these?

To give some examples:

000001  proc proc1

000002* comment

```
  * comment without line numbers

            continuation marker set ==>               X

        Arbitrary text as continuation
```

Thanks
xAn

Comment: Could you post some more code. Also try to indent all code so that the relative indentation is ok.

Comment: did you find the solution? I'm interested in this too

Answer (score 0):

I've faced something like this when programming an Antlr grammar to parse Cobol sources. Cobol have some characteristics like yours (fixed columns, column is significant, etc).

The only solution I've found for this problem: "pre-process" the input and turned it into some that Antlr could parse without problems!

Ex: In Cobol, an asterisk in column 7 indicates that the line is a comment line; I changed it (the asterisk itself) to ">>" and specified in my grammar that ">>" means that this line is a comment line.